# Laravel hasManyThrough не работает

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть такая таблица

```
categories: id | name | slug, hasMany('App\Product')
Products: id | name | slug | category_id | brand_id, belongsTo('App\Category'), belongsTo('App\Brand')
Brands: id | name | slug |, hasMany('App\Product')
```

Проблема в том что, когда я пытаюсь вывести производителей в категории вот этой функцией

```
// category model

public function brands()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Brand', 'App\Product' 'brand_id', 'id');
}
```

То производители либо не выводятся, либо выводятся не правильно (не в своей категории). Есть ли другой способ получить производителей через товары?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отношение hasManyThrough работает для случая
`Model 1` -> hasMany -> `Model 2` -> hasMany -> `Model3`
`Model 1` -> hasManyThrough -> `Model 3`

В вашем случае это

`Category` -> hasMany -> `Product` -> belongsTo -> `Brand`

Попробуйте поменять отношение `Product::brands` на `hasOne` или `hasMany`. Семантически это не очень правильно, но практически сломать ничего не должно, работает примерно одинаково.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Решил это таким способом public function brands($ids = [])
    {
        return Brand::whereHas('products', function($q) use($ids)
        {
            $q->whereIn('id', $ids);
        }
        )->get();
    }
}}